# (Non-)Existence of certain invariant distributions on a p-adic space

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions, p-adic-analysis

Following Bernstein-Zelevinski, an $\ell$-space is a Hausdorff, locally compact totally disconnected topological space. For an $\ell$-space $X$, denote $S(X)$ the space of Bruhat-Schwartz functions on $X$, i.e., the space of $\mathbb{C}$-valued locally constant, compact supported functions on $X$. A distribution on $X$ is defined to be an element in $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(S(X),\mathbb{C})$. Denote by $S^*(X)$ the space of distributions on $X$. Let $G$ be an $\ell$-group which acts on $X$. Then $G$ acts on $S(X)$ as $(g.f)(x)=f(g^{-1}.x),g\in G,f\in S(X), x\in X$. This induces an action of $G$ on the distributions: $(g.T)(f)=T(g^{-1}.f)$. A distribution $T$ is called $G$-invariant if $g.T=T$ for all $g\in G$. Denote by $S^*(X)^G$ the space of $G$-invariant distributions on $X$.

Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field.

$\textbf{Question 1}$: Let $G=F^\times \times F^\times$ and $X=F^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$. Let $U=(F^\times)^3$ which is an open subset of $X$. Let $G$ act on $X$ by $(a,b).(x,y,z)=(ax,by,abz)$. Is there a $G$-invariant distribution on $X$ such that its restriction to $U$ is non-trivial? If such $T$ exists, what can we say about $Supp(T|_U)$?

$\textbf{Question 1'}$: Let $G,X,U$ be as in $\textbf{Question 1}$. Let $\mu=\psi(z/(xy))d^*xd^*yd^*z$, viewed as a distribution on $U$. Here $\psi$ is an additive character of $F$. Is there a $G$-invariant distribution $T$ on $X$ such that $T|_U=\mu$?

Here is one example in my mind that suggests the non-existence of distributions $T$ in Question 1. Consider the multiplicative action of $F^\times$ on $F$, and let $U=F^\times$, which is an open subset of $F$. Then by Tate's thesis, there is no $F^\times$-invariant distribution $T$ on $F$ such that $T|_U$ is non-zero. In fact, the only $F^\times$-invariant distribution on $F$ is the Dirac measure.

But if we consider the action $(a,b).(x,y,z)=(ax,by,a^{-1}b^{-1}z)$ in $\textbf{Question 1}$, there clearly exists $G$-invariant distribution on $X$ (even on $F^3$, say the usual Haar measure $dxdydz$ on $F^3$) such that its restriction to $U$ is non-trivial.

Here are some thoughts on Question 1. Let $Z=X-U$. Then there is an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow S^*(Z)^G\rightarrow S^*(X)^G\rightarrow S^*(U)^G$$
Let's take an element $T_0\in S^*(U)^G$ and asks the question: is it possible to extend $T_0$ to a distribution on $X$? Given a function $\phi\in S(F)$, we can define a distribution $T_0$ on $U$ by
$$<T_0,f>=\int_U f(x,y,z)\phi(z/(xy))d^*xd^*yd^*z, f\in S(U).$$
But it seems that there is no obvious way to extend $T_0$ to $X$. For example, if $f\in S(X)$, the integral $ \int_U f(x,y,z)\phi(z/(xy))d^*xd^*yd^*z$ is not well-defined in general, even when $\phi$ has compact support. But I don't know how to characterize $S^*(U)^G$ in general, and I also don't know how to show the above $T_0$ cannot be extended to a $G$-invariant distribution on $X$.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

I asked part of the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409933/extension-of-certain-invariant-distributions, but did not draw much attention, and thus I decided to move it here. If it is not permitted, I will delete one.

Comment: Reference for the notion "distribution" that you use?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar A distribution on an $\ell$-space (Hausdorff, locally compact, totally disconnected topological space) $X$ is just a linear dual of $S(X)$, where $S(X)$ is the space of compact supported locally constant functions on $X$, i.e., a distribution is an element in $Hom_{\textbf{C}}(S(X),\textbf{C})$. The standard reference is Bernstein-Zelevinski, "Representations of $GL(n,F)$, where $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field"

Comment: Thanks.  The word "distribution" is used in other senses in mathematics as well, so this is useful.  Maybe lack of definition was even the reason that other question got little attention.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks for your comments. I will try to add these definitions to the question.

Comment: @QingZhang: for question 1 what about the distribution given by the constant function equal to 1?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Do you mean $\varphi\mapsto 1$ for every $\varphi$? This one is not linear. But I probably misunderstood your point.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I think that one is not $G$-invariant. Because $d(ax)=|a|dx$ and the $G$-action is $(a,b).(x,y,z)=(ax,by,abz)$, we have $d(ax) d(by) d(abz)=|a|^2|b|^2 dxdydz.$ Am I right?

Comment: @QingZhang: Yes and no. $G$-invariance is defined relatively to a multiplicative character so I guess we used different ones. It would help if you gave the definition of $G$-invariance in your question.

Comment: I would use the word principal value (and show the similarity with $D'(\mathbb{R}^*) \ni 1/x \mapsto pv(1/x) \in D'(\mathbb{R})$) as it is really what you want to adapt to local fields